# Not able to reach from one instance to other

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, trace, packet-capture

I have 2 aws ec2 instances and facing reach-ability issue from one instance to another. Have checked for SG, IGW, and it looks fine. Have also added subnet in /etc/hosts.allow to allow the hosts.
Can someone please suggest how to debug this reach-ability issue ?
I'm trying with

```
 telnet <ip of other ec2 instance> <port>
```

from one ec2 instance to check if one instance is able to connect to open port where service is running of other instance.

Can capturing packet trace from source and destination will help? If yes, what will be the command for it  ?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the current configuration of the security group(s), and let us know on which ports you would like the instances to communicate. Are they both in the same VPC? Are you using their public IP address or private IP address to communicate with each other?